# How to convert a HED model to Tensorflow Lite model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm creating a model from using [holy-edge](https://github.com/moabitcoin/holy-edge). Then, I would like to convert this model to Tensorflow Lite for Mobile usage. I followed [steps here](https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc) and was able to convert the model to .pg file with output_node_names=predictions . For next step, I need to convert .pg file to Tensorflow Lite model by using [toco](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/devguide) but I don't know where to find some required parameters such as input_array, output_array, input_shape and output_node_names.

Does anyone know how to convert a HED model to Tensorflow Lite mode? Please help.

Thanks,
Duc

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
gf = tf.GraphDef()   
m_file = open('frozen_inference_graph.pb','rb')
gf.ParseFromString(m_file.read())

with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    for n in gf.node:
        the_file.write(n.name+'\n')

file = open('somefile.txt','r')
data = file.readlines()
print ("\noutput name = ")
print (data[len(data)-1])

print ("Input name = ")
file.seek ( 0 )
print (file.readline())
```

In my case I had

```
output name: SemanticPredictions
input name: ImageTensor
```